# Reshape 1d CSV to 2D CSV using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv formated like:

| movie_id | ratings |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{'customer_id': 1, "star": "5"}, {'customer_id': 3, "star": "4"}, {'customer_id': 2, "star": "3"}] |
| 2 | [{'customer_id': 1, "star": "4"}, {'customer_id': 2, "star": "3"}, {'customer_id': 3, "star": "5"}] |

which i want to transform to:

|  | customer_id_1 | customer_id_2 | customer_id_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| movie_id_1 | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| movie_id_2 | 4 | 3 | 5 |

How it can be done by using python pandas ?

Comment: Is there really a square bracket, `[`, in your first row of `ratings`?

Comment: @9769953 Yes, i has edit, it's a list.

Comment: Please don't change the data as it will be confusing to a new user who visits your question. Please add changes to data as postscript to your question @hajuha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode the dataframe on ratings and apply series on the dictionary column. An elongated row format is better for manipulation than the one you have specified.

```
df = df.explode('ratings')
df[['customer_id', 'star']] = df.ratings.apply(pd.Series)
```

Output

```
   movie_id                          ratings  customer_id star
0         1  {'customer_id': 1, 'star': '5'}            1    5
0         1  {'customer_id': 3, 'star': '4'}            3    4
0         1  {'customer_id': 2, 'star': '3'}            2    3
1         2  {'customer_id': 1, 'star': '4'}            1    4
1         2  {'customer_id': 2, 'star': '3'}            2    3
1         2  {'customer_id': 3, 'star': '5'}            3    5
```

If you still want your format, follow the code below

```
df.drop(columns=['ratings']).set_index(['movie_id', 'customer_id']).unstack(['customer_id'])
```

Output (Multi-index Dataframe)

```
            star      
customer_id    1  2  3
movie_id              
1              5  3  4
2              4  3  5
```

If there's missing star value for a customer and/or a movie. Using `fillna` will help.

```
df.drop(columns=['ratings']).set_index(['movie_id', 'customer_id']).unstack(['customer_id']).fillna(0)
```

Comment: What if not every movie is rated by all customer. How can I add a default 0 value for the missing values ?

Comment: This is not mentioned in the question. Hence, I have not considered it. Checkout `fillna` method in pandas.